# Dynamically changing HTML value from Android

Tags: android, html, cordova

Am using `WebView to load HTML file` , which is stored in `assets/www` directory.

HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>PhoneGap</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script>

new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 6,
  interval: 6000,
  title: '@palafo',
    width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#ad0000',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#444444',
      links: '#ad0000'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: true,
    loop: false,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('CareerBuilder').start();

</script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

This html file loads the twitter page in my webview, using .

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/twitter.html");
```

Now i wanna change the User name dynamically, here in this case Username is CareerBuilder , now i want to change that name dynamically when i click in my ListView i.e., CareerBuilder to x or y etc..,.

How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have same app  i used below code.....

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("introduction.html");
            int size = is.available();

            // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();

            // Convert the buffer into a string.
            str = new String(buffer);

            str = str.replace("XXXX", days);
```

Change in HTML file ....

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=300, user-scalable=no">
        <title>Intro</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
                font-family: Helvetica;
                font-size: 25px;
                background-color:#000000;
                color:#A4C639;
            }
            td {
                text-align: center;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="width: 300px;">
        <table width="100%" style="margin-top: 5px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Welcome to the Voting Card<font size="1">tm</font> App, only</b>
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="font-size:130px;font-weight:bold;">XXXX</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="font-size:18px;">
                    Days Until the Nov. 6th, 2012 Presidential election.
                    <br/><br/>
                    Check back periodically to see what else the U.S. Congress in Washington, D.C.
                    is voting on and stay in contact with your elected officials.
                    <br/><br/>
                    For more information about VOTING CARDtm and its upcoming features visit us at
                    <br/><br/>
                    www.capitolgamescience.com
                    <br/><br/>
                    or email us at
                    <br/><br/>
                    votingcard@capitolgamescience.com
                    <br/><br/>
                    Thank you for using our app,
                    <br/><br/>
                    Capitol Game Science Media, LLC
                    <br/>
                    <br/><br/>
                    We respect your privacy and abide by applicable U.S. privacy laws.
                    None of your personal information will be retained or recorded.
                    Your emails and web browsing will be conducted from your device.
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Am not able to get the replace thing, i tried by declaring a variable in script and using that to replace but its not changing its going as Undeclared ..